# Help factoring matrices out of cross-covariance

Tags: covariance, linear, covariance-matrix, matrix, random-vector

I am trying to prove that $\text{Cov}( \boldsymbol{BU},  \boldsymbol B' \boldsymbol W) = \boldsymbol B \text{Cov}(\boldsymbol U, \boldsymbol W) \boldsymbol B'^T$, where

- $\boldsymbol B$ is $j \times m$
- $\boldsymbol B'$ is $k \times n$
- $\boldsymbol U$ is $m \times 1$
- $\boldsymbol W$ is $n \times 1$.

I will show my work below, but it's gross and I can't see my way to showing the equality. Can somebody either show me how equality holds in what I've done below, or show me a "high-level" proof of the equation that doesn't get bogged down in this mess? Thanks.

\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}( \boldsymbol{BU},  \boldsymbol B' \boldsymbol W) &=  \text E \big[ (\boldsymbol{BU} - \text E (\boldsymbol{BU}))(\boldsymbol B' \boldsymbol W - \text E (\boldsymbol B' \boldsymbol W))^T \big]\\ \\
&= \text E
\left[\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i = 1}^m \big( b_{1i}U_i  - \text E(b_{1i}U_i) \big)\\
\sum_{i = 1}^m \big( b_{2i}U_i  - \text E(b_{2i}U_i) \big)\\
\vdots\\
\sum_{i = 1}^m \big( b_{ji}U_i  - \text E(b_{ji}U_i) \big)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{i = 1}^n \big(b'_{1i}W_i  - \text E(b'_{1i}W_i)\big) & \sum_{i = 1}^n \big(b'_{2i}W_i  - \text E(b'_{2i}W_i)\big) & \cdots & \sum_{i = 1}^n \big(b'_{ki}W_i  - \text E(b'_{ki}W_i)\big)
\end{pmatrix}\right]\\ \\
%&= \text E
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
&\boldsymbol B \text{Cov}(\boldsymbol U, \boldsymbol W) \boldsymbol B'^T\\
&= \boldsymbol B \text E \big[ (\boldsymbol U - \text E (\boldsymbol U))(\boldsymbol W - \text E (\boldsymbol W))^T \big] \boldsymbol B'^T\\ \\
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{11} & b_{12} & \cdots & b_{1m}\\
b_{21} & b_{22} & \cdots & b_{2m}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
b_{j1} & b_{j2} & \cdots & b_{jm}\\
\end{pmatrix}\\
&\begin{pmatrix}
\text E\big(U_1 - \text E(U_1)\big)\big( W_1 - \text E(W_1) \big) & \text E\big( U_1 - \text E(U_1) \big)\big( W_2 - \text E(W_2) \big) & \cdots & \text E\big( U_1 - \text E(U_1) \big)\big( W_n - \text E(W_n) \big)\\
\text E\big( U_2 - \text E(U_2) \big)\big( W_1 - \text E(W_1) \big) & \text E\big( U_2 - \text E(U_2) \big)\big( W_2 - \text E(W_2) \big) & \cdots & \text E\big( U_2 - \text E(U_2) \big)\big( W_n - \text E(W_n) \big)\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\text E\big( U_m - \text E(U_m) \big)\big( W_1 - \text E(W_1) \big) & \text E\big( U_m - \text E(U_m) \big)\big( W_2 - \text E(W_2) \big) & \cdots & \text E\big( U_m - \text E(U_m) \big)\big( W_n - \text E(W_n) \big)
\end{pmatrix}\\
&\begin{pmatrix}
b'_{11} & b'_{21} & \cdots & b'_{k1}\\
b'_{12} & b'_{22} & \cdots & b'_{k2}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
b'_{1n} & b'_{2n} & \cdots & b'_{kn}
\end{pmatrix} \text{ (note that this is a product, but due to space limitations the matrices have been stacked)}
\end{align*}

Comment: The math seemed better-formatted when I was writing the post. I'm not sure what happened. Sorry.

Comment: Which objects are random variables and which are constants??  Presumably $B$ is constant, in which case you are just trying to show a special case of the bilinearity of covariance.  Depending on how you define covariance, this is either part of the definition or it is easy algebra in one dimension--but that's all you need.

Comment: @whuber The B matrices are constant. There is a vastly more elegant solution to this at https://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Matrices.html, so that's what I'm trying to piece together now.

Comment: The bilinearity of covariance reflects the linearity of the expectations used to define it.  Bilinearity, expressed in matrices, says $\operatorname{Cov}(AU,B^\prime V)=A\operatorname{Cov}(U,V)B$ for any constant matrices $A$ and $B$ compatible with the dimensions of the random variables $U$ and $V.$  Thus, *the only observation you need to make* is to apply bilinearity to the case $A=B.$